# Error: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "USERS" not found

Tags: sonarqube

Hi I am trying to reset admin password. I am using sonarqube 7.1 version. As per the official doumnetation i am using the below update query to reset password.

update users set crypted_password = '88c991e39bb88b94178123a849606905ebf440f5', salt='6522f3c5007ae910ad690bb1bdbf264a34884c6d' where login = 'admin';

but after executing this I am getting the below error and the password has not been reset.

Error: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "USERS" not found; SQL statement: update users set crypted_password = '88c991e39bb88b94178123a849606905ebf440f5', salt='6522f3c5007ae910ad690bb1bdbf264a34884c6d' where login = 'admin' [42102-176]

please help me on this.